# Read XML File and Save data to SQL Table Columns using c#

Tags: c#, xml, model-view-controller

i want to read following file and read and save tag by tab value to sql table column. following is my xml file. i am doing this in mvc.

```
XMl FILE:

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.009.001.01">
        <MndtInitnReq>
            <GrpHdr>
                <MsgId>10005226074</MsgId>
                <CreDtTm>2018-10-23T15:20:56</CreDtTm>
                <InstgAgt>
                    <FinInstnId>
                        <ClrSysMmbId>
                            <MmbId>ARTD0211860</MmbId>
                        </ClrSysMmbId>
                        <Nm>ATEST BANK</Nm>
                    </FinInstnId>
                </InstgAgt>
                <InstdAgt>
                    <FinInstnId>
                        <ClrSysMmbId>
                            <MmbId>40123424</MmbId>
                        </ClrSysMmbId>
                        <Nm>test t CO-OP. BANK LTD</Nm>
                    </FinInstnId>
                </InstdAgt>
            </GrpHdr>
        </MndtInitnReq>
    </Document>
```

Comment: where is the `tab` value in your xml?

Answer (score 0):

You need to deserialize the XML to c# type , Then insert this object in the database using entityframework

First create a C# class (Model) representing your XML schema and Mark it as Serializable 
you can easily do it  by creating a new class , let's call it TestClass for example and Copy your XML file into the clipboard (Ctrl+A, Ctrl+C)
and In Visual Studio, go to Edit menu and select "Paste Special"->"Paste XML as Classes".

```
// open a stream containing the file content (the XML) using stream reader
FileStream ReadFileStream = new FileStream(<YOURFILELOCATION>, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);

// Create a new XmlSerializer instance with the type of the test class
XmlSerializer SerializerObj = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TestClass));

// Load the object saved above by using the Deserialize function
TestClass LoadedObj = (TestClass)SerializerObj.Deserialize(ReadFileStream);
```

then using EntityFramework you can save this C# object to database